# expected class name before { token c++

Tags: c++, class, abstract

I have an abstract class:

```
template<class tip>
class apsMatrica
{
    public:
    virtual int find_max( int k) = 0;
    virtual bool GaussElim (std::vector<tip> &b) = 0;
    virtual std::vector<tip> vracanje (const std::vector<tip>& b)  = 0;
    virtual std::vector<tip> sustav (std::vector<tip> b) = 0;

};
```

And new class:

```
template <class tip>
class Matrica : public apsMatrica
{
 //some code here
}
```

If I don't put ":public apsMatrica" after definition class Matrica then code works just fine

```
template <class tip>
class Matrica 
{
 //some code here
}
```

else it doesn't work and there is error :

```
 expected class-name before '{' token
```

I have included .h file into .cpp file, and i wonder what could be the problem?

Comment: `class Matrica : public apsMatrica<tip>` ??

Comment: Your initial statement is wrong. You don't have a class, you have a class *template*.

Comment: In addition to the missing template argument, you're also missing a semicolon after the closing brace of the `class Matrica` definition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`apsMatrica` is a class template so do this:

```
class Matrica : public apsMatrica<tip> //or any other type
```

Comment: Strictly speaking, it's a "class template", not a "template class". (A template class is a class (e.g. `apsMatrica<int>`). A class template is a template.)